# Subcaption box size in a TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, subcaption

I want to insert auto-referenced labels (a), (b), ... for grouped pictures, but the node boxes which contain these labels come out to be too large:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    subcap/.style={
        text width=1.3em,   anchor=north west,  inner sep=0pt,
        fill=none,          scale=4,            draw
    }
}
                                                                              
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}                                                              
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis} \addplot[domain=0:3] {x^2}; \end{axis}
            \node[subcap] at (current bounding box.north west) {\subcaption{}\label{subfig}};
            \node[subcap] at (current bounding box.south west) {(a)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: wrong: top, right: bottom]

How do I remove all unnecessary whitespace from the box with `\subcaption` (top) to
yield the result in the bottom?

Comment: with \node[subcap] at (current bounding box.north west) {\subcaptiontext*[1]{}}; in the doc subcaption.pdf p.19

Comment: @pascal974 works, thank you very much